# " I am ashamed that I should have been involved in the case." (involved really?...)

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

> " I am ashamed that I should have been involved in the case."

The speaker was involved in the case really? or he regrets not having been involved?

'should+have+pp' is generally used when someone regrets something that (s)he didn't do in the past.

Comment: This seems like a very old-fashioned way of saying it.  I would expect a modern speaker to say "I am ashamed that I was involved" or "...that I have been involved."

Answer (score 1):

We can use 'should' to talk about something that happened, that we are surprised or sorry about:

> Should
>
> Surprise or regret
>
> We sometimes use should to express surprise or regret about something
> that happened:
>
> *I’m amazed that he should have done something so stupid.*
>
> *I’m sorry that he should be so upset by what I said.*

[Should (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/should)

Comment: Thx. 'should have pp' can be used to describe something we regret not having done and something we are surprised at which actually happened in the past. I think it's used more to regret.

Comment: It's not a very common usage. Very confusing to learners of English because throughout their most of their learning journeys, this additional usage is not taught.

Comment: @Brandon - equally regret and surprise, and I have heard it for pride and pleasure too. I am proud that a member of my family should have won the Nobel Prize; I am ashamed that a member of my family should have gone to prison for fraud.

Comment: @Yuri.teacher.English - quite common usage.

Answer (score 0):

The speaker was involved and wishes that had not happened.

If the speaker meant

> I should have been involved and am ashamed that I was not.

that's what should have been said.

Comment: Thx. English is interesting^^.

Comment: Does using "should have" instead of "had" put distance between the speaker and their actions, by avoiding more direct language? Does the use of "should" as a form of shall also impart any extra sense of force to the action itself (even if it's softening the actor's connection to it), so as to more forcefully condemn the action?

Comment: Would the "should have" in this sentence be contracted to "should've" like the other use of "should have" mentioned in the original question (ought to have)?

Comment: @DanGetz "Should've" would be OK but informal. I don't quite understand the question in your other comment. There are too many hypotheticals. Perhaps ask another question where you provide several alternative constructions along with your thoughts about each.